CP-SAT Explanation for interleave_search and interleave_batch_size
I am looking for more information in the above topics. The documentation shows the following;
  // Experimental. If this is true, then we interleave all our major search

  // strategy and distribute the work amongst num_workers.

  //

  // The search is deterministic (independently of num_workers!), and we

  // schedule and wait for interleave_batch_size task to be completed before

  // synchronizing and scheduling the next batch of tasks.

  optional bool interleave_search = 136 [default = false];

  optional int32 interleave_batch_size = 134 [default = 0];

From this discussion, I found (and experienced) that interleave_batch_size must be > 1 for exploiting parallel workers (solvers).
"The interleave search is deterministic, and what will happen is that "batch size" tasks will be scheduled on your "num workers" each time."
Two questions;

Does this mean that our outputted solution should be the same from run-to-run, while for  interleave_search = False, this is not the case?

What is a proper setting for interleave_batch_size if interleave_search is used? This post hints at twice the number of workers for non interleave search




yes. Search should be deterministic for a given number of workers.
There may be some bugs around clause sharing that may not be deterministic.
Basically, it creates num_workers * interleave_batch_size tasks, run them, then synchronize and starts the next batch.

